# Schema diagram of dependencies of mat views

Tags: postgresql

I have several materialized views that require other materialized views when being built. For example, mat view A needs mat view B to be built. These mat views have no foreign key or other relationships between them.

I have the following questions:

1. Is there a tool I can use to generate what mat views need what other mat views to be built?

   I am using schemaspy currently, but it looks like it is creating the schema diagram looking at foreign key relationships only. Since, my mat views don't have those relationships, the diagram is not correct.
2. I have written the following code to show me all dependencies of all mat views, but I am not sure how to automatically make a diagram out of it.

```sql
select distinct (ref_cl.relname, rwr_cl.relname)
  from pg_depend dep
  join pg_class ref_cl on dep.refobjid = ref_cl.oid
  join pg_namespace ref_nsp on ref_cl.relnamespace = ref_nsp.oid
  join pg_rewrite rwr on dep.objid = rwr.oid
  join pg_class rwr_cl on rwr.ev_class = rwr_cl.oid
  join pg_namespace rwr_nsp on rwr_cl.relnamespace = rwr_nsp.oid
  where dep.deptype = 'n'
  and dep.classid = 'pg_rewrite'::regclass
  and rwr_cl.relkind = 'm'
```

**UPDATE**

Output of the above query -

```
(admit, acute)
(admit, discharge)
(admit, calc)
(attending, admit_trend)
(calc_acute, calc_metrics)
```

Comment: can you share the output of this query please

Comment: @HaleemurAli Updated my question with the output of the query.

Comment: Completely unrelated, but: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. `distinct (a,b)` would actually be an error in other databases. All that the expression `(a,b)` does, is to create a single record (with an anonymous record type) that contains two fields.